# Using RunImpersonated for an HttpClient call fails for a NUnit test, but works in Console

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit, impersonation, .net-core-3.1

I need to have my tests run as a testing account.  To accomplish that I setup to the following code to create a handle into my testing account:

```
SafeAccessTokenHandle testAccountHandle;

bool returnValue = LogonUser("TestAccount", "myDom.net", 
       "pass", 2, 0, out testAccountHandle);
```

I can then make a call to load a URL:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated<Task>(testAccountHandle, async () =>
{
    var url = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
});
testAccountHandle.Dispose();
```

When I run this in a console application, it works just fine. (Likewise in LinqPad.)

However when I run this code in an NUnit test, I get the following error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

It says it is usually a temporary error, but it happens every single time I run impersonated in the NUnit Test, and never when I run in the Console.  It also never happens when I run in the NUnit test if I am not running impersonated.  (In short it ONLY happens when in an NUnit Test and Impersonated.)

I am not sure how to go about debugging this.  It seems clear that NUnit does not like my impersonation, but I am not sure what to do about it.

**How can I make a successful `HttpClient.GetAsync` call while using `RunImpersonated` in an NUnit test?**

NOTE: Full repro code can be found here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3672

Comment: If you log in as the test user and open up a browser, are you able to visit the url successfully or do you get an error? What about running nslookup on accounts.google.com as the test user? I just want to confirm that it's not a problem with your network configuration

Comment: @kylejrp - I am able to visit the URL just fine when logged in as the test user.  Also, it runs just fine when not run in an NUnit Test (but still run in code as the test user).

Comment: Is it maybe something to do with the context in which you've declared `httpClient`? It looks like you're declaring it outside of the scope of `RunImpersonated`, I wonder if that would affect the user that the `HttpClient` uses. This is a shot in the dark, but what if you declare `httpClient` in scope of the impersonation?

Comment: @kylejrp - Sounded promising, but I just tried it and it still fails.

Comment: @kylejrp - I posted this on the NUnit GitHub site: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3672  I posted a full repro there if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with .NET Core. See the open issue and discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29935

> It seems that WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated() works differently in .NET Core compared with .NET Framework. This is causing a variety of issues including one affecting ASP.NET Core, #29351.
>
> There is some difference in the way that the identity token permissions are getting set on the impersonated token. This is causing "access denied" issues in a variety of ways.

### Workaround

[Issue #29351 from ASP.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29351) references this exact error message and contains a workaround. Setting the environment variable `DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER` to `0` disables the SocketsHttpHandler and makes this problem go away. For example, the following works without the error:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_SYSTEM_NET_HTTP_USESOCKETSHTTPHANDLER", "0");
HttpResponseMessage response = null;

await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated<Task>(testAccountHandle, async () =>
{
    var url = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
});
```

You may need to make considerations for only setting this environment variable for this specific test and not for every test. I'm not sure what the impacts of disabling the SocketsHttpHandler are, so use the workaround at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am accepting this as the answer, but I would add (for future readers) that this setting was removed in .Net 5.0.  So this workaround is for .Net Core ONLY.